# Proving some properties of digital sum of an integer

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

[image]

For part a we can prove that eventually the sum of the digits will go on decreasing and become a one digit integer and then it will be a constant.

Am I right?

I mainly need help in part b as I am having no idea to prove it.

Any help will be truly appreciated.

Comment: Hint. What can $p$ be modulo $9$ if $p+2$ is also prime?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have shown part $a$ we can define $F(n)$ the be the limiting value of $f^i(n)$.  We note that $F(n)\equiv n\pmod 9$ as $f(n)\equiv n \pmod 9$.

Now take any pair $p, p+2$ of twin primes other than $3,5$.  Since $p>3$ we must have $p\equiv \pm 1 \pmod 3$.  But $p\equiv 1 \pmod 3\implies p+2\equiv 0 \pmod 3$ so in fact we must have $p\equiv -1 \pmod 3$ whence we can write $p$ in the form $3k-1$.  It follows that $p+2=3k+1$ whence the product is $9k^2 -1$.  In particular the product is $-1\equiv 8\pmod 9$ so we are done.